# How to just rename a field in an aggregation pipeline without removing other fields?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

guys.
I have an aggregation and a fields map, that I need to rename. Problem is, that the structure is not defined, so I don't really know which attributes will be in resulting output.

In the end, I need to rename fields without removing other ones.
Example:

```
[
...
{
   field1: "value1", 
   field2: "value2",
   field3: "value2",
   field4: "value4",
}
...
]
```

For example, I want to rename output field field2 to myNewField. With $project I got:

```
[$project: {
  "myNewField": "$field2"       
}]
```

In this case only myNewField is displayed:

```
`
[
...
{ 
   myNewField: "value2"
}
...
]
`
```

Expected result:

```
[
...
{
   field1: "value1", 
   myNewField: "value2",
   field3: "value2",
   field4: "value4",
}
...
]
```

Thank you & have a nice day!

Comment: Use `$addFields` (or `$set`) instead of `$project`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an stage just before the project using `$set` to add the new field and into the `$project` use the exclusion (`0`) with the field you don't want to output:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "myNewField": "$field2"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "field2": 0
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/a_CoYGodTA-)